# Can I take this backpack on board an EasyJet flight in addition to my cabin bag?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, easyjet, backpacks

I have an EasyJet flight soon (AMS to TLV). I have this backpack and a cabin mini-suitcase. My mini-suitcase is fine, but I'm worried they'll give me trouble with the backpack, and I don't have a big suitcase into which I could put it if push comes to shove.

So, what are my chances to bring this backpack:

[image]

onboard? (It's a [Columbia TreadLite 22L](http://www.columbia.com/treadlite-22l-backpack-UU9069.html))

Note: No speculation or quoting official policy please, just answers based on your experience or cases you have particular knowledge of.

Comment: You mean on-board as in hand luggage? Are you worried about the size or what?

Comment: @Kuba: Hand luggage, under-seat luggage, stuff it in the overhead compartment luggage, whatever.

Comment: But are you worried about the size or the fact that it's a backpack? Looking at cabin bag allowance at their website it's clear they'd allow it, have you checked it?. And depending on your fare you can take one or two pieces, it's all on their website.

Comment: @Kuba: I already have a cabin bag - my mini-suitcase. This is supposed to be the extra thing I take onto the cabin. Sometimes some airlines give me trouble with it, claiming that it's like a second cabin bag.

Comment: well isn't it a second cabin bag? On their website it's clearly written you can have one personal item and with some special cases / fares second one. First Google result: http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/baggage/cabin-bag-and-hold-luggage

Comment: I flew with EasyJet last April. No extra bags allowed (unless you paid extra for your ticket) and that started with small hand bags. Your pack stand no chance.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a buddy and his response was no. Since your only allowed 1 carry on, but if you were really lucky they would allow it, but you would need to have a smaller backpack. All depends how laid back they are, but usually they will say "no"

Comment: Can you add some details about your buddy's experience?  Does he work for EasyJet, or has he flown with them a lot?  As it stands, this answer sounds like the opinion of a Random Guy On The Internet™, and we all know how much that's worth.